# Keys aren't doing what they're suppost to

Tags: python, key, pygame

I'm using pygame to draw a line:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Drawing Lines")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_DOWN:
            sys.exit()


    screen.fill((0,80,0))

    color = 100,255,200
    width = 8
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (100,100), (500,400), width)

    pygame.display.update()
```

for some reason, I can't get this is work:

```
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_DOWN:
                sys.exit()
```

It doesnt show any error, it just doesnt work. I want to be able to press the down key and have it quit the program but it doesnt do that. I have to quit the idle. Any help will do. thanks.

Comment: scroll down to the bottom of this page, there are some examples of the kind of thing you appear to be trying to do. http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.event.get

Answer (score 1):

This is because `KEYDOWN` is just the event that a *key is pressed down*, not that the *down key* has been pushed. To fix this, you have to first check if a `KEYDOWN` event has happened, and if it has, check what key that was pushed.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_DOWN:
        sys.exit()
```

Check out the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) on this subject to learn more.

Comment: import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Drawing Lines")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_DOWN:
            sys.exit()
    

    screen.fill((0,80,0))
    
    color = 100,255,200
    width = 8
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (100,100), (500,400), width)

    pygame.display.update()

Comment: import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Drawing Lines")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_DOWN:
            sys.exit()
    

    screen.fill((0,80,0))
    
    color = 100,255,200
    width = 8
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (100,100), (500,400), width)

    pygame.display.update()